# javafx populate dynamic tableview from database with checkbox

Tags: sqlite, checkbox, tableview, javafx-8

I want to populate a dynamic tableview from database with 32 columns,First column contain the name of employee and remaining 31 columns for marking employee attendence from day1 to day31(checkbox).But I can able to populate tableview from database with 2 columns(name,checkbox) using get and set methods.Here is my **code**

```
    String sql ="SELECT * FROM attendence";
    pst =   (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            //get string from db,whichever way 
            String name=rs.getString(3);
            int day=rs.getInt(6); 
            data.add(new User(name,day!=0)); //converting integer to boolean and storing on data(Observable list)
        }

         etname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
         col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("day1));

         col.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<User, Boolean>,       TableCell<User, Boolean>>() {

         public TableCell<User, Boolean> call(TableColumn<User, Boolean> p) {

            return new CheckBoxTableCell<User, Boolean>();

        }
          });

           jTable.getColumns().add(etname,col);
            jTable.setItems(data);
             }
```

This is **User.java**

```
   public class User {


      private final SimpleStringProperty ename;
      private BooleanProperty day1;

      User(String Ename,boolean day1)   
      {
        this.ename = new SimpleStringProperty(Ename);
        this.day1 = new SimpleBooleanProperty(day1);

        this.day1.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {

                System.out.println(enameProperty().get() + " invited: " + t1);
                System.out.println();
            }

        });            

    }


    public String getEname() {
        return ename.get();
      }


    public void setEname(String Ename) {
    ename.set(Ename);
   }


   public BooleanProperty day1Property() {
     return day1; 
    }


  public StringProperty enameProperty() {
    return ename;
    }
```

**CheckBoxTableCell.java**

```
 public class CheckBoxTableCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {

    private final CheckBox checkBox;

    private ObservableValue<T> ov;



    public CheckBoxTableCell() {

        this.checkBox = new CheckBox();

        this.checkBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);



        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        setGraphic(checkBox);

    } 



    @Override public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {

        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {

            setText(null);

            setGraphic(null);

        } else {

            setGraphic(checkBox);

            if (ov instanceof BooleanProperty) {

                checkBox.selectedProperty().unbindBidirectional((BooleanProperty) ov);

            }

            ov = getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getIndex());

            if (ov instanceof BooleanProperty) {

                checkBox.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional((BooleanProperty) ov);

            }

        }

    }

}
```

But no idea how i can do with 32 columns.
So i need a big help from anyone for my 2 problems.
**1)** How i can populate dynamic tableview from database with checkboxes **2)** when i press a button should read all the names along with checkbox status(isSelected or not selected) like

- jhon true true false ... ....
- rose false false true ... ..
- george    true true true false

Answers will be appreciated.Thank you in advance.
 .. ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this code.

```
  private static final List<String> groups = Arrays.asList("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4"); //declared an array

  TableView<AttributeRow> attributeTable = new TableView<>(); //new Table
   for (String group : groups) {  //Creating dynamic column
        TableColumn<AttributeRow, Boolean> groupColumn = new TableColumn<>(group);
        groupColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(groupColumn));
        groupColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().activeProperty(group));
        attributeTable.getColumns().add(groupColumn);
    }
```

and AttributeRow class

```
class AttributeRow {

private final Map<String, BooleanProperty> activeByGroup = new HashMap<>();


public AttributeRow(List<String> companyGroups) {
    for (String group : companyGroups) {

        activeByGroup.put(group, new SimpleBooleanProperty()) ;
    }
}

public final BooleanProperty activeProperty(String group) {

    return activeByGroup.get(group) ;
}

 public final boolean isActive(String group) {
    return activeProperty(group).get();
}

public final void setActive(String group, boolean active) {
    activeProperty(group).set(active);
}
```

For loading checkbox data(true or false) we can use following method

```
         String sql ="SELECT * FROM attendence";
         pst =   (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
         rs=pst.executeQuery();
         while (rs.next()) {

               AttributeRow row = new AttributeRow(groups);

               for(int j=0;j<5;j++) //here j<5 because array size =5
                           {
                               int i=j+6;
                            int day=rs.getInt(i); //getting Integer value(note:sqlite does not support boolean datatype so i stored as integer with 0 or 1)

                            row.setActive(day!=0); //converted into boolean useing day!=0
                           }
                            jTable.getItems().add(row);

               }
```

Comment: wow working perfectly.But you never explained how to generate data from database

Comment: Wow thank you very much it working perfectly.You saved my day